# Effects of coffee consumption on testosterone production

Tags: health, chemistry

Does consumption of coffee affects hormone, precisely testosterone production in a noticeable way? And if so does it increases it or decreases it?

Also I'm not looking for any type of super scientific answer I just wanted to know to satisfy my own curiosity.

Comment: Which hormones? Probably, caffeine affects many of them all together. There are [plenty number of hormones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_hormones).

Comment: Yeah your right I should mention which

Answer (score 1):

*In short, caffeine may increase "Sex Hormone Binding Globulin" which results decreased levels of testosterone in both men and women.*

However, I don't know how effective it is. Or if this decrease is serious and supported by many studies. I have encountered [this study](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/144/7/642/258244) presents that caffeine's inverse effect on women testosterone level, which is somewhat related to osteoporosis as far as I can interpret.

Please note that people who answer questions here are not professionals in the designated areas.